# Why is not possible to decode and unserialize in the same line? (like this example)

Tags: php, serialization, base64

Why this is not possible?

```
$b64_encoded = base64_encode(serialize(array('test')));

if( $b64_decoded = base64_decode($b64_encoded) && $unserialized = unserialize($b64_decoded) )
{
    var_dump($unserialized);
}
```

Comment: Because of [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). `&&` has higher precedence than `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

What's happened is that PHP sees `$b64_decoded` as an undefined and unset variable because you've got it tied up in your if statement without correctly parting it.

See this:

```
if( $b64_decoded = base64_decode($b64_encoded) && $unserialized = unserialize($b64_decoded) )
```

PHP believes the `&&` has a higher priority over `=`. Your code effectivly is;

```
$b64_decoded = (base64_decode($b64_encoded) && $unserialized) = unserialize($b64_decoded)
```

Which doesn't seem to make any logical sense.

So, we have to tell PHP the priority of the operations and what items are grouped together. We can do this by wrapping our statement with `(` `)`

Such as this:

```
if( ($b64_decoded = base64_decode($b64_encoded)) && $unserialized = unserialize($b64_decoded) )
    ^                                          ^
```

PHP now understands the priority of the statement as you have specified.

Comment: But even with the "not confused" method, the if statement will not work. Right?